# Not getting updates from NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am creating a simple location app that stores the user's location upon command. I am attempting to use both the GPS provider and Network provider to establish the user's location.

The process is achieved using Asynctask and works likes this:

1. Checks last known GPS location and Network location. If locations are within acceptable parameters the thread finishes.
2. If last know locations are unacceptable, updates are requested of  both GPS and Network.
3. Once 4 network locations have been found or either 3 gps locations have been found the thread finishes.

A dialog box is displayed when waiting for a location fix.

**PROBLEM**: GPS seems to be updating whereas Network does not. I have tried solely updating NETWORK_PROVIDER, waited for over an hour with no results. I have tried with both WIFI on and off.

The code for the GetGPS class:

```
public class GetGPS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements LocationListener {

    private ProgressDialog progDialog;
    public double[] DataArray = {0.0,0.0,0.0};
    private Integer NetworkCount = 0;
    private Integer GPSCount = 0;
    private LocationManager mlocManager;       
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;
    final LocationListener locationListener = (LocationListener) this;
    private boolean HasCompleted = false;


    public GetGPS(Context context, Activity activity) {
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = activity;   
    } 


    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        Log.v(getClass().getName(),"PreExecute");


        mlocManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Stop any current GPS updates
        mlocManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);

        //Get current system time in millis
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Check last known GPS location and corresponding accuracy and time
        String GPSlocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Location lastKnownGPSLocation = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(GPSlocationProvider);

        if (lastKnownGPSLocation != null) {
            long lastGPStime = lastKnownGPSLocation.getTime();
            long timeDifference = currentTime - lastGPStime;
            float lastGPSaccuracy = lastKnownGPSLocation.getAccuracy();
            Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Found last known GPS! GPS time diff:"+timeDifference+", Accuracy:"+lastGPSaccuracy);
            if ((lastGPSaccuracy < 50) && (timeDifference < 180000)) {
                Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Acceptable last known GPS location!");
                DataArray[0] = (double) lastKnownGPSLocation.getLatitude(); 
                DataArray[1] = (double) lastKnownGPSLocation.getLongitude(); 
                DataArray[2] = (double) lastKnownGPSLocation.getAccuracy();
                HasCompleted = true;
            }
            else {
                Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Last known location GPS too inaccurate!");
            }   
        }
        else {
            Log.v(getClass().getName(),"No previous GPS locations!");
        }

        //Check last known network location and corresponding accuracy and time
        String NetworklocationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        Location lastKnownNetworkLocation = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(NetworklocationProvider);

        if (lastKnownNetworkLocation != null) {
            long lastNetworktime = lastKnownNetworkLocation.getTime();
            long timeDifference = currentTime - lastNetworktime;
            float lastNetworkaccuracy = lastKnownNetworkLocation.getAccuracy();
            Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Found last known Network location! Time diff:"+timeDifference+", Accuracy:"+lastNetworkaccuracy);
            if ((lastNetworkaccuracy < 50) && (timeDifference < 180000)) {
                Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Acceptable last known Network location!");
                DataArray[0] = (double) lastKnownNetworkLocation.getLatitude(); 
                DataArray[1] = (double) lastKnownNetworkLocation.getLongitude(); 
                DataArray[2] = (double) lastKnownNetworkLocation.getAccuracy();
                HasCompleted = true;
            }
            else {
                Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Last known Network location too inaccurate!");
            }                   
        }
        else {
            Log.v(getClass().getName(),"No previous Network locations!");
        }

        // Request both providers to update
         mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,(LocationListener) this);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,(LocationListener) this);


        //Display dialog box
        progDialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
        progDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Stop", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.v(getClass().getName(),"ProgDialog cancelled");
                mlocManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                GetGPS.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        progDialog.setMessage("Acquiring location..");
        progDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progDialog.show();
        Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Show progdialog");
    }


   @Override
     public String doInBackground(String... params) {
         while (HasCompleted == false) {
                         }
         Log.v(getClass().getName(),"doInBackground completed");
         return "Success";

     }
     @Override
     public void onPostExecute(String result) {
         Log.v(getClass().getName(),"onPostExecute");
         //Destroy Dialog box
         progDialog.dismiss();
         //TODO: Deal with data

     }
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v(getClass().getName(),"onLocationChanged, Provider:'"+location.getProvider()+"'");

            // Check if from Network
            if (location.getProvider().equals("network")){
                Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Network location Changed");
                NetworkCount = NetworkCount + 1;
                if (NetworkCount > 3) {
                    DataArray[0] = (double) location.getLatitude();
                     DataArray[1] = (double) location.getLongitude();
                     DataArray[2] = (double) location.getAccuracy();
                     Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Location stored from Network!");
                     Log.v("data array 0","" + DataArray[0]);
                     mlocManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
                     HasCompleted = true;
                }
                else {
                    Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Network location count:"+NetworkCount);
                }
            } 

            //Check if from GPS
            if (location.getProvider().equals("gps")){
                Log.v(getClass().getName(),"GPS location Changed");
                GPSCount = GPSCount + 1;
                if (GPSCount > 2) {
                     DataArray[0] = (double) location.getLatitude();
                     DataArray[1] = (double) location.getLongitude();
                     DataArray[2] = (double) location.getAccuracy();
                     Log.v(getClass().getName(),"Location stored from GPS!");
                     //Log.v("data array 0","" + DataArray[0]);
                     mlocManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
                     HasCompleted = true;
                }
                else {
                    Log.v(getClass().getName(),"GPS location count:"+GPSCount);
                }
            } 

     }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.v("OnProviderDisabled", "OnProviderDisabled:"+provider);
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.v("onProviderEnabled", "onProviderEnabled:"+provider);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            Log.v("onStatusChanged", "onStatusChanged, provider:"+provider+", Status:"+status);

        }

    }
```

The GetGPS class is called in the following manner:

```
Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
Activity mActivity = getActivity();
GetGPS getgps = new GetGPS(mContext, mActivity);
getgps.execute();
```

Any help as to where i'm going wrong? Thank you in advance forany help.

**Also:** Is there a simple way to implement a timeout for the Asynctask? I.e. If no location fix is found after a set time period, the thread stops.

Answer (score 0):

About your first question, please check that both GPS and Network providers are enabled at your phone:
[image]

I'm also not sure if implementing LocationListener inside AsyncTask is the proper way, I tried to read about it and came across [this](http://blog.alwold.com/2013/05/15/gps-in-an-asynctask-in-android/). Try to read it and implement the solution he propose. (What I would do is create an independent location Singelton class which will have nethods such as stop and start and will be controlled from the AsyncTask).

At your doInBackground method, I would change the While loop, and just put a Thread.sleep(50) inside. to prevent busy waiting.

About your second question, the simplest thing to do here is check the time that has passed in the while loop of doInBackground and stop the thread there is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Both providers are enabled within the phone (I am testing on my phone rather than a emulator). I have also ensured that all relevant permissions are stated within the android manifest file. I don't understand how it works for GPS_PROVIDER but not NETWORK_PROVIDER, surely my general method should be acceptable?

Comment: What do you mean by general method?

Comment: I mean the method of implementing LocationListener within AsyncTask. I say this beacuse the method seems to completely work for GPS_PROVIDER but not NETWORK_PROVIDER, which is causing a little bit of a headache.

Comment: What happens when you subscribe to network location updates within a regular class? does that work?

Comment: I will try that and post the results. I have read about using the google Fused location provider, does this have any advantages over the methods of manually updating network/gps?

Comment: Sure. It saves you the time from trying to decide what provider to use and it might save battery in the long run as it shares resources between apps. As for me I'm not a fun and usually use the old methods.

Comment: Thanks @Ohad for your help. I ended up changing the code to use the Fused Location provider which was contained in an independent class and it works like a dream.